# Parsing percentage from webservice is displayed as numbers

Tags: ios

```
[offStr setString:[offStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *offrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:offStr]];
    NSLog(@"%@",offStr);
    [offrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:offrequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

        NSURL *offurl = [NSURL URLWithString:offStr];
    NSData *offdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:offurl];
    NSDictionary *offjson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:offdata options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray *offarr = [offjson objectForKey:@"Response"];
    NSMutableArray *offersArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary* offers = [offarr objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *offersInside = [offers objectForKey:@"0"];
    for (int i=0; i<offersInside.count; i++) {
        NSString *offerstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:[offersInside objectAtIndex:i]];
               NSLog(@"%@",offerstr);

       [offersArr addObject:offerstr];
        NSLog(@"%@",offersArr);
```

I get the following in my log:

> 256607337541FF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS.
>   25,000 and 306607337541FF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS
>   OVER RS. 25,000 but my actual string is  25% OFF ON DIAMOND AND
>   GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS. 25,000

Comment: may be this is your order id 256607337541FF

Comment: can you print this dictionary *offjson*

Comment: Response =     (
             {
            0 =             (
                "25% OFF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS. 25,000",
                "30% OFF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS. 25,000",
                "50% offer for every first purchase"
            );
            id = 1;
        }
    );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 NSMutableArray *offersArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSData *offdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:offStr]];
NSArray *offersInside  = [[[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:offdata options:kNilOptions error:nil]objectForKey:@"Response"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"0"];
[offerArr addObjectsfromArray: offersInside];
```

Comment: {"Response":[{"id":"1","0":["25% OFF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS. 25,000","30% OFF ON DIAMOND AND GEMSTONE JEWELLERY ORDERS OVER RS. 25,000","50% offer for every first purchase"]}]}

Comment: this is my url reponse

Comment: have a happy day my sister,